# Opencart: how to filter order list by product model?

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, opencart

i am trying to search order list by product `model` filter. there is already had some filter that customer name, order id, order status, etc... i need product `model` also like this. 
any idea.?

[image]

Comment: Either edit this by viewing the templates in admin. Or find a vQmod for this - their is a mod for this though I am sure of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at last i find out the solution for this problem, try this free module:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3597&filter_search=order%20list%20filter%20model&page=4